# Move UIBarButtonItem few pixels down?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, backbarbuttonitem

I have created a custom `UINavigationBar` which is a tiny bit taller than Apples default navigation bar.

I can’t seem to find a way to move the `UIBarButtonItem` down to be directly centered between the two dashed lines.

Is there an easy way to do this? I’ve tried creating a custom button but had no success. Ideally I would just like to move the default back button down a couple of pixels.

[image]

Code used to create `UINavigationBar`, custom header image and `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
    //Create image for navigation background
UIImage *NavigationPortraitBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbackground.png"]
                                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: NavigationPortraitBackground
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

//Centered title image
UIImageView *headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"hometitle.png"]];
    [headerImage setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 49)];
self.navigationItem.titleView = headerImage;

UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[backBarButtonItem setTintColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:69.0/255 blue:118.0/255 alpha:1]];
[backBarButtonItem setStyle: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
[backBarButtonItem release];
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: maybe modifying the dashed line is easier?

Comment: If that is the only solution then I may have do to that. Will wait a little while to see if anyone else has any other suggestions.

Comment: how are you creating the custom UINavigationBar and also adding the UIButton to it?

Comment: @AdamH did you find a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Create the UIBarButtonItem using a custom view. This custom view will be a UIView with the actual UIButton (as a subview) placed x pixels from the top (x=the number of pixels you want to move it down).

Answer (score -1):

sorry

```
UIButton *myButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
 [myButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];   myButton1.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;  
 myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 3.0, 50,30);  
  [myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton1];    
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
```

Comment: Get a warning - "'UIBarButtonItem' may not respond to 'setFrame:’” and it causes the program to crash.

Comment: sorry   


UIButton *myButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [myButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    myButton1.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 3.0, 50,30);
    
    [myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    
    UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton1];
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;